# Project management software that will allow me to plan classes and functions

Tags: php, uml

I'm working on a big PHP web-project and I was wondering - Is there any Project Manager software that will allow me to plan the "skeleton" of the project - meaning the classes, input & expected output of functions and things like that?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Comment: UML diagrams (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) coupled with ERDs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model)? Free online with Gliffy http://www.gliffy.com/uml-software/

Comment: When I read the title, I thought you were advertising that you were trying to hire a project manager that let the developers do the planning of classes and functions. I giggled. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use UML to define classes.

There is a good free software called starURL.

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

[image]

Comment: Thank you and @SpyrosP and @Treffnnon and @glowcoder for the quick answer.

But, I am looking for something that will also allow me to add descriptions for the functions - and I can't seem to find it on both of this softwares... Something I'm missing here?

And, I'd prefer something that will also work with windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Umbrello in the past. Pretty nice and open source :)

http://uml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect from [Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com) is native on Windows, can do PHP forward and reverse engineering, and has a whole bunch of functionality around project planning and tracking where you mark model elements as Proposed, Implemented, etc, and create tasks and things.

I haven't played around much with either, though, I just know it's there. Also, EA is a commercial product if that's an issue.